# extract key-value at an unknown level

Tags: json, select, jq

```
jq -r .x <<< '{"x": "abc"}'
```

When I am sure which level a key-value I want to extract, I do something like the above.

What if I am not sure which level it is, like in `{..., {"x": "abc"}, ...}`? How can I extract the value in this case (suppose there is one such match, or I only care about the first match)?

Comment: Check out [RecursiveDescent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) `..`

Comment: Is it the most succint way to extract? `jq -r '..|.x?|select(.!=null)'  <<< '{"y": { "x": "abc" } }'`

Comment: You could also go with `.. | .x? | values` or `.. | .x? // empty`. -- Here's another one using `paths` and `getpath`: `getpath(paths | select(last == "x"))` -- Wrap any of these with `first` to get only the first match.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I extract the value

Assuming you regard `null` as a value, and that you want at most one .x value,
I would venture to say that the most succinct expression (code-golf style) would be:

```
first(..|select(has("x")?).x)
```

Note that this will yield the empty stream if there is no .x value.

---

The following is slightly shorter but has different behavior if there is no "x" key:

```
[..|select(has("x")?).x][0]
```